# How to write Unit Test for String equals Java?

Tags: java, oop, junit, mockito, backend

I am writing Junit to Update Menu Item in Menu List Item. In process, It will check every Menu Item names in Menu Item Lists to find if anything equals with changeItem or not. If it equals then set new values for MenuItem Object. However, I doesn't know how to write Unit test for this service.

**My code:**

```
   @Override
public void updateMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu) {
    try {
        menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);
        System.out.print("Insert menu item want to update:");
        String changeItem = scanner.nextLine();

        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().forEach((MenuItem menuItem)->{
            if(menuItem.getNames().equals(changeItem)){
                System.out.print("\nInsert name: ");
                menuItem.setNames(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Insert description: ");
                menuItem.setDescription(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Insert image: ");
                menuItem.setImage(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Insert price:");
                menuItem.setPrice(scanner.nextFloat());
            }
        });
    } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException exception){
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    } catch (InputMismatchException exception){
        System.out.print(new InputMismatchException("Menu item quantity must be number !!!").getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you micking a LIST? cant you just use list with data?...... That is doing easy things the hard way.

Comment: also: don't declare a Scanner within your method, do that on class level. don't "read" the input in that method, pass the input as parameters

Comment: Didn't understand what you are trying to achieve here "doReturn(noodle).when(foodItem).equals(changeItem);"

Comment: I am trying to get the MenuItem from the List based on changeItem keyword and set new values for that MenuItem.

Comment: I'd consider the method implementation that you post as untestable (which is illustrated by your problems of coming up with a test). Typically that means that you'll introduce an indirection through additional classes/interfaces/methods that are easier to test in isolation. UI code is often messy to test, while the conditions (`if`) and error handlers are relatively easy. You're just swallowing error conditions, so no outside test can determine what happens when the user enters "really cheap" for a price (instead of a float).

Comment: On top: Under those conditions, your menuItem will already be updated with a new name, description and image - just not with an updated price. I doubt that you'd like this implementation to be correct (and you wouldn't cement this with a test)

Answer (score 1):

Don't sure to answer but like i see this quickly :

```
@Test
void updateMenu(){
DailyMenu dailyMenu = DailyMenu();
MenuItem menuItem= new MenuItem();
menuItem.setNames("Pasta");
dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().add(dailyMenu);

Scanner mockScanner = mock(Scanner.class);
//set up the scanner
 when(mockScanner.nextLine()).thenReturn("Pasta");
InputOutput inputOutput= new InputOutput(mockScanner);
   
yourClasse.updateMenu();

 assertEquals("Pasta", inputOutput.getInput());
assertEquals(dailyMenu.getNames(),inputOutput.getInput());
 }
```

Hope it can help you.